# Jboss Failed to instantiate class "org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandle

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss6.x

When I tried jbosseap6.3 install as service. I got below error. Anyone have any idea on the below error. Any one shed light means it is very helpful for me.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to instantiate class "org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler" for handler "FILE"
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.AbstractPropertyConfiguration$ConstructAction.validate(AbstractPropertyConfiguration.java:119)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.LogContextConfigurationImpl.doPrepare(LogContextConfigurationImpl.java:338)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.LogContextConfigurationImpl.prepare(LogContextConfigurationImpl.java:291)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.LogContextConfigurationImpl.commit(LogContextConfigurationImpl.java:300)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:542)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:97)
    at org.jboss.as.logging.logmanager.ConfigurationPersistence.configure(ConfigurationPersistence.java:149)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:300)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager.readConfiguration(LogManager.java:262)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:399)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:396)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:396)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.access$800(LogManager.java:145)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:345)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.ensureLogManagerInitialized(LogManager.java:338)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:378)
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:443)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.config.AbstractPropertyConfiguration$ConstructAction.validate(AbstractPropertyConfiguration.java:117)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\jboss-eap-6.3\standalone\log\server.log (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler.setFile(FileHandler.java:154)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler.setFile(PeriodicRotatingFileHandler.java:105)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler.setFileName(FileHandler.java:192)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:122)
    at org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler.<init>(PeriodicRotatingFileHandler.java:73)
    ... 23 more
Shutdown JBossEAP6.3.0 service [2015-05-29 09:58:27]
```

Answer (score 9):

Try to start jBoss server as administrator by pressing right mouse key, it will permit jboss to create all folders and files .

Answer (score 4):

Right click the installation directory of Jboss EA (mine is C:\program files\EAP6.1, then Properties, Security tab. Given everyone permissions on this folder (all users you can see just give full control). This should then be able to create logs etc files within the required folder. 
This is just a workaround though only works for local installs.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, it worked after running it on root, maybe you are running it without the proper rights.

Answer (score 1):

I had resolved this issue by creating log directory in the 
C:\jboss-eap-6.3\standalone\

Answer (score 1):

it's a problem due to permissions, the solution that worked for me is that i removed the home directory of jboss wildfly from C:\programmes to C:\

Answer (score 1):

Starting Wildfly/Jboss from the **administrator** cmd worked!!

Comment: It looks like the server is already up and running by another process. Please, read the exception. Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\jboss-eap-6.3\standalone\log\server.log (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely getting this error because you either have the log file open in a text editor or you're already running that instance of JBoss.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same exception
Try changing the path from c to another destination, that solved my issue and I am able to start the server

Answer (score 0):

For me, it's working now

1. Jboss wildfly find your logging.properties file.
2. inside the file find this tag,

handler.FILE.fileName=C:\jboss_wildfly\server.log

Create and set the dir as it is.